# Plotting interactive choropleth map in australia?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, interactive

I want to plot an interactive map using the following dataframe:

```
    id          geometry                                            sigmoid
    102011028   POLYGON ((151.41373 -33.46559, 151.41361 -33.4...   0.410899
    102011029   POLYGON ((151.35398 -33.49854, 151.35397 -33.4...   0.615718
    102011030   MULTIPOLYGON (((151.20460 -33.53298, 151.20456...   0.386825
    102011031   POLYGON ((151.36795 -33.43822, 151.36791 -33.4...   0.373488
    102011032   POLYGON ((151.31006 -33.42699, 151.31020 -33.4...   0.040321
```

Basically the geometry represents some area and I have a sigmoid function for each area.

I made a normal choropleth map just using the standard `matplotlib` .plot() which gives me this:

[image]

**code**:

```
merged.plot(column='sigmoid', cmap='OrRd', linewidth=0.8, ax=ax, edgecolor='0.8')
ax.axis('off')
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='OrRd', norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1))
sm._A = []
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm, shrink=0.6)
```

However I want to make it interactive so I can hover and see the sigmoid of each area.

It's the same idea as the interactive choropleth map done using `plotly` but my areas are just in a very small part of Australia so the scope and projection are not suitable.

If anyone could provide some sample code that'd be very appreciated!

**edit** print(df[0:2].to_dict())
[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and share the code you used to create the map?

Comment: More importantly, would you share a reproducible example of your dataset? If it is a pandas dataframe you can share `print(df[0:2].to_dict())`.

Comment: i added my `print(df[0:2].to_dict())` result